# High CPU Usage of I/O dispather thread when using RestHighLevelClient (elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client 7.10.2)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient, elasticsearch-rest-client

We are seeing 100% cpu utilisation on containers with elasticsearch high level client. We have stopped the ingestion onto the cluster and we are still seeing containers at 100%.
***top*** command shows all of the cpus are busy executing i/o dispatcher commands

[image]

Comment: you just stopped the ingestion but search is still happening correct? can you disable the all the operations in the cluster and check again?

Comment: Yeah. Searching is also stopped. Still the same top command result. I/O dispatcher commands are always taking up the 100% cpu

Comment: Where you able to diagnose the issue? I’ve been encountering almost the exact same thing